# Connection failed. Unable to connect to the server that is specified in the url

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, connection, reportbuilder

I'm trying to connect SQL Server Report Builder 3.0  to SQL Server 2008 R2. When I click on connect (on builder 3.0) it returns the above connection error. SQL Server Reporting Services on ie is up and running but every time I click on Report Builder button on SQL Server Reporting Services (in internet explorer), it opens up report builder 1.0 instead of 3.0 .

I tried different changes on my link but none worked. There were posts suggesting adding / to the end of my link, it didn't work either.

I use Web Services URL from Report Services Configuration Manager. I tried many online suggestions, uninstalled, and reinstalled Builder 3.0 compatible with SQL Server 2008 R2. None worked so far. I'm using win 8.1 if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

In a normal local network environment if your SSRS server was called `myServer` then you would view the reports with

`http://myServer/Reports` . This is the web portal (called Report Manager in earlier versions I think)

Report Builder needs to connect to the service url with, using our example this would be

`http://myServer/Reportserver`

If this does not help, then please show the connection you have tried and also show the connection that works that you use to get to the SSRS Home page (where you see your reports listed).